# How to Delete a row from jtable as well as database when selecting checkbox?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I need to delete the specific row from database as displayed in jtable. I want to add action listener on the delete button. But I am kind of new to java programming so facing problems.[image]

My table code is as follow...

```
 rt= st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login");
       DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) usertable.getModel();
       while(rt.next()){
           username = rt.getString(2);
           firstname = rt.getString(5);
           lastname = rt.getString(6);
           emailid = rt.getString(1);
           accounttype = rt.getString(4);
           model.addRow(new Object[] {username, firstname, lastname, emailid, accounttype});
```

Comment: Please read about actionListener on this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html also clear your question whether you want to delete row on checkbox checked or on button click

Comment: Deleting from the JTable really means deleting from the table's TableModel. If you've created the model yourself, then your model will likely have the method to do this, and the method would then call a fire notification method inherited from the AbstractTableModel parent. If you did not create a model, then likely you're using a DefaultTableModel and would call its `removeRow(...)` method.

Comment: As for the database, you would create and execute a PreparedStatement that has a DELETE command in it, and the details can be found with a little Googling, something I **highly** suggest you do (perhaps before even coming here with this question).

Comment: I have added my table code. can you help a bit more?

Comment: @JatinDogra: you're using a DefaultTableModel, so for the model, simply call `deleteRow(...)` as the DefaultTableModel API and the Swing tutorial tells you to do. You really should do more searching this stuff on your own though as your question is very broad, perhaps too broad precisely because you've not done this step yet.

Comment: Note that there are examples out there to be found that combine Swing table model with database structure. I think that Rob Camick's blog has an example of this, and I'll try to find the link for you.

Comment: Please check out [these results](https://www.google.com/?q=camick+java+jtable+database#q=camick+java+jtable+database).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting from the JTable really means deleting from the table's TableModel. If you've created the model yourself, then your model will likely have the method to do this, and the method would then call a fire notification method, here `fireTableRowsDeleted(...)` inherited from the [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) parent. If you did not create a model, then likely you're using a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) and would call its `removeRow(...)` method.

As for the database, you would create and execute a PreparedStatement that has a DELETE command in it, and the details of which will depend on your database and your code.

- [Swing JTable and TableModel Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).
- [Java Database Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)